# How do I error check against a response existing in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to scrap some data off of city-data.com. I want to get the city and state, which I can do. But I can't seem to get my if/else to run if the zip code doesn't exist.

```bash
baseURL="https://www.city-data.com/zips"
errorResponse=" <title>Page not found - City-Data.com</title>"

location=$( curl -s -dump "$baseURL/$1.html" | grep -i '<title>' | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1 )

if $location = $errorResponse;
then
  echo "That zipcode does not exist"
  exit 0
else
  echo "ZIP code $1 is in " $location
fi
```

That script gets me this output when I run `bash getZipcode.sh 30001`

```
getZipecode.sh: line 10: <title>Page: command not found
ZIP code 30001 is in  <title>Page not found - City-Data.com</title>
```

Line 10 is `if $location = $errorResponse;` I removed the author headings I put in my script and the She-Bang for conciseness.

Anyone able to help me figure this out?

Comment: Use `if [ "$location" = "$errorResponse" ];` or `if [[ $location = $errorResponse ]];`

Comment: `-dump` is short for `--data ump`, I doubt that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your `if` statement, you can try with that:

```bash
baseURL="https://www.city-data.com/zips"
errorResponse=" <title>Page not found - City-Data.com</title>"

location=$( curl -s -dump "$baseURL/$1.html" | grep -i '<title>' | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1 )

if [ "$location" = "$errorResponse" ];
then
  echo "That zipcode does not exist"
  exit 0
else
  echo "ZIP code $1 is in " $location
fi
```

The problem was when executing the if statement, the program tried to run the content of your variable as if it was a system command in path.

For more informations on how to compare strings in bash, you can have a look [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash/).

Answer (score 1):

That site like most sites returns a 404 HTTP response code when the page can't be found, so you may want to use that instead for a more reliable approach:

```
export ZIP="$1"
curl -sw '%{http_code} %{errormsg}\n' "https://www.city-data.com/zips/$ZIP.html" |
   perl -ne '
     $location = $1 if m{<title>.*?\((.*?)\)};
     if (eof) {
       if (/^(\d+) (.*)/) {
         if ($1 eq "200") {
           if (defined($location)) {
             print "ZIP code $ENV{ZIP} is in $location\n"
           } else {
             die "Can'\''t find location in the HTML\n";
           }
         } elsif ($1 eq "404") {
           die "That ZIP code does not exist\n"
         } else {
           die "HTTP error: $2\n"
         }
       } else {
         die "curl did not return an HTTP code\n"
       }
     }'
```

Note that `-dump` is interpreted by `curl` the same as `-d ump` or `--data ump`, which is about passing `ump` as HTTP POST request data. You must be confusing with the `-dump` option of `lynx`/`elinks`/`w3m` where that option dumps a text rendering of the HTML page. `curl` is not a web browser, it doesn't do HTML rendering and if it did, you wouldn't be able to find `<title>` in its output.

Since we're already using `perl`, rather than using `curl` to do the HTTP request, we could also use `perl`'s `LWP` module which would make the handling of error cases even easier and cleaner.

Comment: When I saw you piping `curl` into `perl` I was going to make a comment saying pretty much what you said in your last paragraph, about using [LWP](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl).   You've already said that, so I'll add that using LWP also opens up the option of using one of perl's many html parsing and web-scraping libraries - my current favourite, that I've been using for a few years now is [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/release/Web-Scraper), which makes it very easy to extract data by CSS selectors or XPATHs, as well as just parsing the HTML.